SSE Response sent three to four times at once
I am trying to set up SSE between a NodeJS Server and a TypeScript Frontend. My Server-code looks as following:
let sseInterval: { [index: string]: NodeJS.Timer } = {};
this.app.get('/events/:id', (req, res) => {
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    };
    res.writeHead(200, headers);

    const instanceId = req.params.id;
    const instance = this.findInstance(instanceId);

    if (!instance) {
        global.logger.debug('sse closed', {metadata: {for: instanceId}})
        clearInterval(sseInterval[instanceId]);
        res.end();
        return;
    }

    global.logger.debug('sse connected', {metadata: {for: instanceId, instance: instance.config()}})
    res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(instance.all())}\n\n`);

    sseInterval[instanceId] = setInterval(() => {
        global.logger.debug('sse interval', {metadata: {for: instanceId}})
        res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(instance.all())}\n\n`);
    }, 1000);


    req.on('close', () => {
        clearInterval(sseInterval[instanceId]);
        res.end();
    });
});

For the frontend, i am using the following code:
const datapolling = () => {
    let eventSource: EventSource = new EventSource(window.server.url + '/events/' + window.server.key);

    eventSource.onopen = (event) => {
        console.log('connected', event);
    }

    eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        console.log('onmessage', new Date(), event);
        const json = JSON.parse(event.data);

        updateGUI(json);

    };

    eventSource.onerror = (event) => {
        console.error('error', event);

        setTimeout(datapolling, 500);
    };

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
        eventSource.close();
    });
}

console.log('polling', new Date());
datapolling();

The problem is, that the frontend only receives the evenets every 3000ms but 3-4 at once. If i set the backend intervall to 500ms, i get the frontend events every 1500ms, again 3-4 at once.
Is there anything obvious i am doing wrong?

Basic implementation of SSE (server sent events): Unidirectional sent events from server :
Server side :
this.router.get("/sse", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  // SSE Headers
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.flushHeaders();

  //SSE
  const sseId = new Date().toDateString();
  this.writeEvent(res, sseId, `START`);
  this.writeEvent(res, sseId, `0`);
  this.writeEvent(res, sseId, `1`);

  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.writeEvent(res, sseId, `END`);
  },2000);

  //On close event end SSE event emission
  res.on("close", () => {
    res.emit("close");
    res.end();
  });
});

Front end side : 
const source = new EventSource("http://localhost:8000/api/sse");

source.onopen = () => {
  // console.log("SSE opened!");
};

source.onmessage = (e: MessageEvent) => {
  // In my case I am using alert to see data 
  // alert(e.data);

  const p = e?.data;

  //Send close event to sse open channel
  if (t == "END") {
    source.close();
  }
};

source.onerror = (e: Event) => {
  console.error("Error: ", e);
};


I do know the basic setup, see my code above. The problem is that i am receiving the response multiple times and in an unexpected timing

It was a network related issue. I could not figure out what exactly it was but after enabling (and later disabling again) HTTP/2 in my nginx reverse proxy, everything worked out smoothly.
